# Print the elements which making min cost path from a start point to end point in a grid

Tags: algorithm

We can calculate min cost suppose take this recurrence relation

min(mat[i-1][j],mat[i][j-1])+mat[i][j];

0 1 2 3

4 5 6 7

8 9 10 11

for calculating min cost using the above recurrence relation we will get for min-cost(1,2)=0+1+2+6=9

i am getting min cost sum, that's not problem..now i want to print the elements 0,1,2,6 bcz this elements are making min cost path.

Any help is really appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose, your endpoint is `[x, y]` and start-point is `[a, b]`. After the recursion step, now start from the endpoint and crawl-back/backtrack to start point.

Here is the pseudocode:

```
# Assuming grid is the given input 2D grid
output = []
p = x, q = y
while(p != a && q != b):
    output.add(grid[p][q])
    min = infinity
    newP = -1, newQ = -1
    if(p - 1 >= 0 && mat[p - 1][q] < min):
        min = matrix[p  -1][q]
        newP = p - 1
        newQ = q

    if(q - 1 >= 0 && mat[p][q - 1] < min):
        min = mat[p][q - 1]
        newP = p
        newQ = q - 1

    p = newP, q = newQ
end

output.add(grid[a][b])

# print output
```

Notice, here we used `mat` and `grid` - two 2D matrix where `grid` is the given input and `mat` is the matrix generated after the recursion step `mat[i][j] = min(mat[i - 1][j], mat[i][j - 1]) + grid[i][j]`

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thnks. This is without extra grid. Is it possible to do this at a once whn calculating min cost without backtracking?
output = []
p = x, q = y
while(p != a && q != b):
    min = infinity
    newP = -1, newQ = -1
    if(p - 1 >= 0 && mat[p - 1][q] < min):
        min = matrix[p  -1][q]
        newP = p - 1
        newQ = q

    if(q - 1 >= 0 && mat[p][q - 1] < min):
        min = mat[p][q - 1]
        newP = p
        newQ = q - 1

    p = newP, q = newQ
    output.add(mincost-mat[p][q])
    mincost=mat[p][q]
end

output.add(mat[p][q])

Comment: You're welcome and well-done for your improvement without extra space :) Yes, its possible to do without back-going but that will cost more space as you need to carry grids taken so far for all possible path. I think this back-going approach won't hurt because its very common approach like LCS, LIS and other dynamic programming problems.

Answer (score 0):

Besides computing the min cost matrix using the relation that you mentioned, you can also create a *predecessor* matrix.

For each cell (i, j), you should also store the information about who was the "min" in the relation that you mentioned (was it the left element, or is it the element above?). In this way, you will know for each cell, which is its preceding cell in an optimal path.

Afterwards, you can generate the path by starting from the final cell and moving backwards according to the "predecessor" matrix, until you reach the top-left cell.

---

Note that the going backwards idea can be applied also without explicitly constructing a predecessor matrix. At each point, you would need to look which of the candidate predecessors has a lower total cost.